# How to convert normal python code into a python function

Tags: python

Here i have written a normal python code for api request. I need to write this same code in python function. I have no idea how to convert this. So can anyone please let me kknow how to do this.

```
import requests

import json

r = requests.post(

"https://api.xxxxxxxx",

data={

'text': "i won the match",

},

headers={'api-key': 'MY_SECRET_API_KEY'}

)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: dont post your api keys here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion to the code: I've taken liberties to clean up a bit. The function has the URL and text parameters as arguments:

```py
import requests
import json

def call_url(url, text):
    r = requests.post(
        url,
        data={'text': text,},
        headers={'api-key': 'MY_SECRET_API_KEY'}
    )
    print(r.text)

call_url("https://api.deepai.org/api/sentiment-analysis", "i won the match")
```

Answer (score 1):

In short you need to or rather should do 3 things:

1. Define the *function* using the keyword `def` following by the functions name
2. Follow the function name with parentheses with your parameters optionally in them followed by a semi-colon
3. Indent your functions code
4. Optionally but typically you'd end the function with a `return` statement

You can learn more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

```
import json
import requests

def process_text_sentiment(text):
    r = requests.post('https://api.deepai.org/api/sentiment-analysis',
                      data={'text': text},
                      headers={'api-key': 'MY_SECRET_API_KEY'})

    return r.text

print(process_text_sentiment('i won the match'))
```